# Posting to Facebook wall with Facebook Powershell Module

Tags: facebook, powershell, facebook-graph-api, permissions

I've been trying to figure out how this API works, and I found some very neat [tutorials](http://www.amandhally.net/2012/08/14/facebook-module-for-powershell/).

However, I cannot seem to replicate what he does in his tutorial. Whenever I try to make a new connection (New-FBConnection), I get
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aVGE.png). It cleary says at the bottom "This does not let the app post to Facebook, and the only information I can edit is whether or not to provide my email to the app.

And in the aforementioned tutorial, he had all the permissions right of the bat.

I've tried with the parameters like "New-FBConnection -ExtendedPermissions", but what ever I type following that only opens a random home page of Jon Newman.

So my question is, how do I add more permissions to the Facebook PowerShell Module, to allow it to post to a Facebook page?

Comment: Publishing permissions are only asked for on the _second_ screen of the login dialog; the first one _always_ says _“This does not let the app post to Facebook.”_

Comment: I never get a second screen of login dialog

Comment: Well, that tutorial is over three years old already – so it might not be up-to-date with the latest API changes. Are you testing this with a user that has a role in the app? Otherwise, you need to submit your app for permission review, before you can ask common users for any additional permissions (besides the three basic ones.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that tutorial is outdated. On April of last year the Facebook platform had a big change with the v2.0 Graph API. I would recommend to look for another tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated this API is outdated, and with the recent changes to the Facebook Graph API it no longer supports these features.